# Janusgraph no labels being created for vertices

Tags: python, janusgraph, gremlin-server

I am working with Janusgraph. For batch-loading, I have defined some schema, including :

```
m   = janusGraph.openManagement()

// vertex labels
contentV = m.makeVertexLabel("Content").make()
...

// edge labels
contentE = m.makeEdgeLabel("content").make
...

// properties
...

m.commit()
```

I am able to create vertices and edges successfully. But the vertices don't have any labels. Edges do have labels.

I tried this for a demo:

```
...
>>> g.addV('Content').property('name','123').next()
v[43475160]
>>> n = g.V(43475160).next()
>>> n
v[43475160]
>>> n.id
43475160
>>> n.label
''
```

Is there something I need to edit in the schema, or is it something else?

I am using gremlin-python package for running gremlin queries from python.

---

#### Update

`g.V().hasLabel('Content').toList()`, do return the nodes, but the nodes have their label as an empty string as shown in the demo.

---

#### Found a solution

I get the label when I use `g.V(123).valueMap(True).toList()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found a solution**

I get the label when I use `g.V(123).valueMap(True).toList()`

The `valueMap(True)` part is responsible, without providing True, I don't get the label